# How to manage visual studio tabs

Tags: visual-studio

I guess I have hundreds opens files in my VS2015 now and it is really a headache to find the one which I need. I remember seeing somebody's VS screen which can pick up some tabs and list them in the left panel of visual studio. Is that a add-on or some configuration is built-in options?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it was my [Task Canvas](https://vlasovstudio.com/task-canvas/) extension that lets you open several small editor windows as tabs in one panel.

Comment: It looks like a nice one that can help in my situation. The only thing is it is not free and I have to spend $49 to purchase.